# Move Cartesian with MoveIt

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, cartesian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i would like to move the robot "Franka Emika Panda" with the cartesian movement in C++. I make the configuration which is recommended on the homepage. My current result is to move the robot with joint movement with moveit. Then I trying the cartesian movement with the following link:

http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html#cartesian-paths

In this section they show how it works with the simulation, but i would like to try this one on the real robot. I hope i can get some tips to solve my problem.

EDIT: I add the source code and the launch-file which i use.

SOURCE CODE

```
//Cartesian Path
geometry_msgs::Pose target_pose3 = move_group.getCurrentPose().pose;

std::cout<< "Anfangsposition" << std::endl;
std::cout<< target_pose3 << std::endl;

std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose> waypoints;
waypoints.push_back(target_pose3);

target_pose3.position.z -= 0.2;
waypoints.push_back(target_pose3); //down

target_pose3.position.y -= 0.2;
waypoints.push_back(target_pose3); //right

target_pose3.position.z += 0.2;
target_pose3.position.y += 0.2;
target_pose3.position.x -= 0.2;
waypoints.push_back(target_pose3);

// Skalierungsfaktor der maximalen Geschwindigkeit jedes Gelenks
move_group.setMaxVelocityScalingFactor(0.1);

moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory;
const double jump_threshold = 0.5;
const double eef_step = 0.01;
move_group.computeCartesianPath(waypoints, eef_step, jump_threshold, trajectory);

moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan goal_plan;
goal_plan.trajectory_ = trajectory;
move_group.execute(goal_plan);
```

LAUNCH-FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<launch>
    <arg name="robot_ip" />

    <include file="$(find franka_control)/launch/franka_control.launch">
        <arg name="robot_ip" value="172.16.0.2" />
        <arg name="load_gripper" value="false" />
    </include>
    <include file="$(find panda_moveit_config)/launch/panda_moveit.launch">
         <arg name="load_gripper" value="false" />
    </include>
</launch>
```

When i start my source code then i get some information back from the console

```
 INFO] [1551336690.500652276]: Received request to compute Cartesian path
[ INFO] [1551336690.501040209]: Attempting to follow 4 waypoints for link 'panda_link8' using a step of 0.010000 m and jump threshold 0.500000 (in global reference frame)
[ INFO] [1551336690.507374299]: Computed Cartesian path with 2 points (followed 2.597403% of requested trajectory)
[ INFO] [1551336690.508019615]: Execution request received
[ WARN] [1551336690.534495590]: Dropping first 1 trajectory point(s) out of 2, as they occur before the current time.
First valid point will be reached in 0.013s.
[ INFO] [1551336690.667268099]: Completed trajectory execution with status SUCCEEDED ...
[ INFO] [1551336690.667388163]: Execution completed: SUCCEEDED
```

Regards,
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316808/move-cartesian-with-moveit/) by [MarkusHHN](https://answers.ros.org/users/34687/markushhn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2019-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mlautman](https://answers.ros.org/users/35816/mlautman/) on 2019-03-05**:
You should always visually inspect the generated plan before executing on hardware. The computeCartesianPath functionality has a known [issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/773) that could result in joint flips.

**Comment by [MarkusHHN](https://answers.ros.org/users/34687/markushhn/) on 2019-03-06**:
thank you for the information. It is possible to solve or improve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand your question correctly, you probably just need to create/update a [plan](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/structmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup_1_1Plan.html) using the trajectory which is I/O in `computeCartesianPath`, and then call [MoveGroup::execute](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html#a82f1bb33058893e8a16fa49af24d689f) with said path.

Assuming the tutorial's notation, this should work:

```
my_plan.trajectory_ = trajectory;
move_group.execute(my_plan);
```

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkusHHN](https://answers.ros.org/users/34687/markushhn/) on 2019-02-28**:
Thank you for your answer, but the robot dont moving to this position. I will add some source code and information